# save some variables posted via form on session and use in next page

Tags: php, html, sql

i have a form like that and i want save name and phone posted by form and use in next page but cant do it .i echo sessions created in this page but nothing happen.   i have a form like that and i want save name and phone posted by form and use in next page but cant do it .i echo sessions created in this page but nothing happen.

```
  <?php

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    
    
    //collect form data
    extract($_POST);

    //very basic validation

    
    if($name ==''){
        $error[] = 'fill name';
    }
    
    if($phone ==''){
        $error[] = 'fill phone';
    }


    
    
    

    if(!isset($error)){

        try {

            $postSlug = slug($postTitle);

            //insert into database
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO order_main (amount,phone,name,order_desc,order_date) 
  VALUES (:amount, :phone, :name, :order_desc, :order_date)') ;
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':amount' => $amount,
                ':phone' => $phone,
                ':name' => $name,
                ':order_desc' => $order_desc,
                
                ':order_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                
            ));
            $order_id = $db->lastInsertId();

            
            //add categories
        
            

            //redirect to index page
            header('Location: ../php-simple-master/payment.php?action=added');
            exit;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    }

    //check for any errors
    if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
    }
    ?>

    <form action='' method='post' >

    <p><label>name</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='name' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['name'];}?>'></p>

    
    
    <p><label>phone</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='phone' value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['phone'];}?>'></p>
    
    
    <p><label>amount</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='amount' value='<?php  echo $_SESSION['total']?>'></p>
    
    <p><label>desc</label><br />
    <input type='text' name='order_desc' value='<?php foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => 
 $product) {
  echo $product['quantity']."*".$product['name']."*".number_format($product['price'], 0)." "."|"." ";
  }?>'></p>
  <?
    
   $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];  
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];

    
    
    
  ?>


   
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p>

</form>
```

Comment: it is conditional form.if have no error then can post date by header:  header('Location: ../php-simple-master/payment.php?action=added'); yes i want use session variables on next page for payment .it save name and phone who want pay for payment gatway.

Comment: I see your are passing the data by session variables. Make sure you are calling session_start(); at the top of your script or the session is auto enabled  by your server

Comment: yes i used session_start() at the top.but here dont used compelete code.

Comment: Are you adding it on your payment.php at the top also ?

Comment: if u means session_start() yes i added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think the issue is you're setting these variables at the wrong point after the exit. Well at least in your above example. Add these lines above the redirect code.

```
  // Set name and phone session
  $_SESSION['name'] = $name;  
  $_SESSION['phone'] = $phone;
  //redirect to payment page
   header('Location: ../php-simple-master/payment.php?action=added');
   exit;
```

Comment: thank u so much dear clive atkins i did it and it work.i wish best for u.